# Dispatching an error with redux is not working

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to dispatch an error with redux to render it on the front-end but i'm not getting anything

Comment: Have you debugged the inner function you pass to post()? Is it invoked at all? What do err and res look like?

Comment: yes it's invoked, i got it on the front end i just can't dispatch the error

Comment: You need to put more context of your problem. Please, put here reducer code and invocation of the action creator and mapping your state to component.

Comment: @Yannis it's not clear what "can't dispatch" means here. Do you see an action in the redux devtools? Do you get an exception when calling store.dispatch?

Comment: I updated, I don't get it on the redux console so it's no action

Comment: And how are you invoking your action creator?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const callApi = payload => dispatch => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    post(`/newlist`, payload)
     .then(response => {
       resolve(response);
     })
     .catch(error => {
       dispatch({
        type: CONSTANTS.EX_ERROR,
        payload: error,
       });
       reject(error);
     });});};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to actually catch the error, it won't return in the body. See below;

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    post(url, payload, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: CONSTANTS.EX_ERROR,
                payload: err
            });
            reject(err);
            return;
        }
        resolve(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
                type: CONSTANTS.EX_ERROR,
                payload: err
            });
        });
});
```

Edit: just saw your type error - you need to wrap the component you're using this function in with a mapDispatchToProps function, this will attach the dispatch function to your redux actions. You can also pass dispatch tothe function from the store but I wouldn't recommend this approach. Below is the basic implementation of this.

```
export class YourComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {

    state = {

    }

    public render() {
        return (
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
        myActions: bindActionCreators<any, any>(myActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

You would the call your actions via props, e.g. `this.props.myActions.callMyAction(data)`

Within your action you will also need to return dispatch, e.g.

```
return (dispatch: any) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    post(url, payload, (err, res) => {
        ...
        resolve(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
                type: CONSTANTS.EX_ERROR,
                payload: err
            });
        });
});
}
```

Comment: The fact that OP is getting an exception when calling dispatch in their inner function, not in the catch block you added, means this isn't true.

Comment: @timotgl the fact that OP added that within an edit while I was writing this means I didn't see it, this is still correct and would resolve an issue he would've have after

Comment: No it doesn't, it would still show the error in the console if you don't catch it. The dispatch you're using is from the same scope (it's an argument of callApi). Adding a catch block is a good practice but doesn't directly address this particular problem.

Comment: Any idea how to dispatch in this function ? i'm a bit lost haha

Comment: @Yannis I've edited, you will also need to add middleware to your store if you haven't already, e.g. thunk